# How to Convert DurationFormatUtils back to Milliseconds

Tags: java, methods, formatting

Currently I have been using DurationFormatUtils to convert the Millis in a track into HH:mm:ss, but I want to allow the user to seek the track using this format, for example they would type:
'-seek HH:mm:ss or mm:ss' and I want to convert that time back into milliseconds... Are there any built in Java methods to do this? Or would I have to create my own method to convert it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

First, define a `DateTimeFormatter` instance.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss");
```

- `H` - one or two digits of 24 hour time
- `mm` - minutes
- `ss` - seconds

To handle absence of the hours you can check to see if a colon exists from the 3rd character on. If it does, then the time can be parsed as is, otherwise, prepend `00` hours. I chose to put it in a lambda.

```
Function<String,String> adjust = time -> time.indexOf(":",3) >= 0 
            ? time : "00:"+time;
```

Putting it all together.

```
String[] times = { "3:49:44", "12:30" };
for (String time : times) {
    int millis = dtf.parse(adjust.apply(time))
          .get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY);
    System.out.println(millis);
}
```

prints

```
13784000
750000
```

Check out the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package for more date/time classes.